# number of camera frames taken after intervals with opencv on raspberrypi

Tags: python, opencv

I have a code given below. which works fine.i.e it takes  a number of frame after for a couple of seconds then camera turns off and again camera turns on and takes a couples of frames.The code given below works fine on my Desktop whenever i tested that code on raspberry pi  first iteration of for loop works well but on second iteration of for loop it doesn't give VideoCapture returns false

```
 import cv2
 import time
 timeout=time.time()+10
 for f in range(3):
     cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)
       count = 1

      while True:

            ret, img = cap.read()
            print(ret)
            cv2.imshow('image', img)
            cv2.imwrite('Datasets/T' + str(f + 1) + '/' + str(count) + '.tif', img)
            print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
            if time.time() > timeout:
               break

           if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
              break
          count = count + 1

       for _ in range(10):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
       if f!=2-1:
          cap.release()
          time.sleep(delay_after_one_video)
        cap=cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)

       timeout=time.time()+10
```

Comment: Any reason to relase and recreate the videocapture() object? Might be easier to leave it connected and just call read() when you need an image

Comment: to turn off the camera  i am using  release nd recreate the object... also to keep the buffer  empty.

Comment: Why are you using `cv2.destroyAllWindows` inside a loop? You only need to call the function once.

Comment: some times opencv don't destroy the window so i m using in loop.... to get into safe side

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I post an answer.

It's seems that you can not release camera resource.(If so, you can not set the property of camera) Try to build OpenCV by yourself, remember to check the v4l library.